# How to save each and every form input button actions into json file using eihter javascript or jquery or angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I wanted to save my all form inputs, each and every button action(for ng-clicked and non-ng-clicked including file uploads/urls, etc i.e. whatever I click, those values should be stored in json file/object i.e. for all `<input type="button">` in my case), with the given sample structure either using javascript or jquery or angularjs(the sample structure is provided in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/o1bt6pfk/2/)).Here I am getting the each action log at: `console.log('User actions :', $scope.userActions);`, but I need is the same action logs should be stored in a json file with the proper structure for my given all input types. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS supports two-way binding, which means you don't *need* to submit your data.

As I don't know enough about your specific use case I can't get it to fully function, but this should get you going:

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/lhVZxh1zMS8iMtAfnPDg?p=preview)

The main thing is that everything is stored in a scope variable (as JSON):

```
$scope.source = {
    'testingwizard' : 'TestingWizard',
   'firstTitle': 'First Title',
   'nextstep': 'Sub',
    'test': {
      'uploadedurl': '/...abc.html',
      'text': 'TEST'
      },
   'network':   
   {
     'layer0': 'TestValue0',
    'layer1': 'TestValue1',
    'layer2': 'TestValue2',
     'testdata': 'TESTDATA',
     'number': '10'
   },
   'yesname': 'yes',
   'Result': 'TestResult',
};
```

That is active as long as you are on that page, so you can do a $http put to a backend at any time (and have the values you expect).

*PS: I've slightly changed the values in the Plunk (added new prefix) to prove that it's not the HTML providing the values.*

Comment: Hi Spikee, thanks for your reply, but my requirement is that I need to store my each and every action in json file with any structure like above.

Comment: You mean as in an array of JSON objects? You can do that using the above, though this is obviously just a single instance. Your use case is too complex to do that for you (nor should I :P).

Comment: As I am getting all the json array objects: console.log($scope.userActions); - but I am not getting how can I implement this to convert into file with any structure like above or any other ? and in the Plunker, we are defining with custom values, that is not the case actually, it could vary and that's my required sample file structure.

Comment: Could you update your question to describe in higher detail what you need? Reading a JSON array from your backend is easy because it can provide you an array of objects.

Comment: I have updated my question with proper description. kindly check once and let me know for anything please.